# How to layout exact number of elements in a row with a ConstraintLayout's Flow

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I need to layout a few pairs of title-value widgets, each pair being in a single row with title aligned to the start and value to the end of parent.

Items are hosted in a ConstraintLayout and I'd like to use Flow to align them in a desired way.
I tried to use Flow's `app:flow_wrapMode="aligned"`, but it is not enough as I need to have each title in a new row.

Answer (score 3):

What I needed was a `flow_maxElementsWrap` attribute:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:constraint_referenced_ids="amountTitle,amount,deliveryTitle,delivery"
  app:flow_horizontalStyle="spread_inside"
  app:flow_maxElementsWrap="2"
  app:flow_wrapMode="aligned" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/amountTitle"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/amount_title" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/amount"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="$3.00" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/deliveryTitle"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/delivery_title" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/delivery"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="$1.00" />
```